# Select max value under a specified value in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking for a way to select the max id value in a table under a specified value. I am trying to use the following query

```
select max(id) as 'maxid' from proveedor where 'id' < 6666
```

The value I am expecting is 3, but instead I get 7777. Is there a different way to do this?

```
+-------+
|   id  |
+-------+
| 1     |
| 2     |
| 3     |
| 6666  |
| 7777  |
+-------+
```

Comment: Remove the single quotes from your query.  Learn to use quotes correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an `typo` in your `query`:

```
where 'id' < 6666
```

Should be(without the quotes):

```
where id < 6666
```

So the following works as expected:

```
select max(id) as 'maxid' from proveedor where id < 6666
```

> **Demo:** 
>   <kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7dd694/2)</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

Remove the single quote marks from the 'id'. With the single quote marks, MySQL treats it as a string instead of a column. If your column names contain special characters you can use backticks.

```
select max(id) as 'maxid' from proveedor where id < 6666
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `id` would appear to be stored as a string.  If you like, you can convert to a number:

```
select max(id + 0) as maxid
from proveedor
where (id + 0) < 6666;
```

Note that you have misused single quotes in your sample code.  I don't believe this is the root cause of your problem.  Nevertheless, you should learn how to use quotes correctly in SQL.

If you want the value as a string, you can do:

```
select id as maxid
from proveedor
where (id + 0) < 6666
order by (id + 0) desc
limit 1;
```